# React-Adal returns 401 with POST request but 200 with GET request

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to send a POST request to an API that is hosted in Azure and is authenticated through Azure Active Directory. I'm using React with [React-Adal](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal) to send my requests. I configured react-adal using the GitHub repo and this [tutorial](https://itnext.io/a-memo-on-how-to-implement-azure-ad-authentication-using-react-and-net-core-2-0-3fe9bfdf9f36) to guide me.

**adalConfig.js**

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin, adalGetToken } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
    tenant: 'ad5842d4-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
    clientId: '1f89aa20-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', //ClientID of the ReactClient application
    endpoints: {
        demoApi: 'e7926712-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', //ClientID of the DemoApi
        microsoftGraphApi: 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
    },
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    redirectUri: 'https://localhost:44394/',
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage'
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalDemoApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
    adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.demoApi, fetch, url, options);

export const adalTokenFetch = () =>
    adalGetToken(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.demoApi);

export const withAdalLoginApi = withAdalLogin(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints);
```

When I use the adalDemoApiFetch with a GET request it works fine and returns 200 with the list of schedules.

```
const url = `https://localhost:44322/api/Schedules/GetAllSchedules`;

        const response = await adalDemoApiFetch(axios.get, url);
        console.log(response);

        const schedules = response.data;
```

When I use the same adalDemoApiFetch with a POST to add a new schedule to the list it returns a 401.

```
const url = `https://localhost:44322/api/Schedules/AddSchedule`;

        const azureADID = authContext.getCachedUser();
        const token = authContext.acquireToken("e7926712-1111-1111-1111-111111111111");
        console.log(token);

        const options = {
            beginningDateTime: this.state.begDateTime.toJSON(),
            endindDateTime: this.state.endDateTime.toJSON(),
            userID: this.state.userID,
            azureADID: azureADID.profile.oid
        };

        const response = await adalDemoApiFetch(axios.post, url, options);
        console.log(response);
```

I also tried copying out the token and using it in Postman to make the call and it still returns 401. When I use the token that is returned from the function below it works just fine.

```
export const adalTokenFetch = () =>
    adalGetToken(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.demoApi);
```

I use axios to call it in the code below and it works just fine.

```
const url = `https://localhost:44322/api/Schedules/AddSchedule`;

        const azureADID = authContext.getCachedUser();
        const token = await adalTokenFetch();
        console.log(token);

        const options = {
            beginningDateTime: this.state.begDateTime.toJSON(),
            endindDateTime: this.state.endDateTime.toJSON(),
            userID: this.state.userID,
            azureADID: azureADID.profile.oid
        };

        const response = await axios.post(url,
            {
                data: options
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            }
        );

        console.log(response);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why would it work with a GET request and not with the POST request? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I tried working with Axios too. Seems that using axios it is unable to authorize the bearer token. Try using the Adalfetch that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell adalApiFetch you are using POST method instead of GET. It defaults to GET, that is why that works ootb. Use the options object.